# django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist: test using sass_processor

Tags: django, sass

I need help to understand why I cannot compile SASS for production environment using the django-sass-processor app.
I search all my templates and still I cannot find any references to a test template. I am using:

```
Django==1.7.7
django-sass-processor==0.2.2
django-compressor==1.5
```

when trying to run the the following command line provided by django-sass-processor:

```
python manage.py compilescss
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py", line 28, in handle
    templates = self.find_templates()
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py", line 39, in find_templates
    for loader in self.get_loaders():
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py", line 68, in get_loaders
    finder_func('test')
  File "~/virtualenvs/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 136, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist: test
```

When looking at the code, it pass by the line 61 of `compilescss.py` (https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor/blob/master/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py)

```
from django.template.loader import (
                find_template as finder_func)
```

and then it fails at line 68 of the same file which is in a try catch

```
    try:
        # Force Django to calculate template_source_loaders from
        # TEMPLATE_LOADERS settings, by asking to find a dummy template
        finder_func('test')
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Can you help me figure out why this is happening?

My settings are:

```
# in INSTALLED_APPS
'sass_processor',
'compressor',

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = False
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
SASS_PROCESSOR_ENABLED = True
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT + '/sass'



TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I even tried to set `SASS_PROCESSOR_ENABLED = False` which didn't change anything.

Regards
Dominick

Comment: Did you try removing that bit of code looking for 'test' to see what would happen?

Comment: @onyeka yes the next error it returns is ``for loader in template_source_loaders:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable``, I think the first import which is getting the global ``from django.template.loader import template_source_loaders`` is set to None straight in django, but it seems like it is never initialized to anything else after that. I opened an issue on github https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor/issues/4 because I am not so familiar with the TEMPLATE_LOADERS. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I finally debugged it myself and I pushed a PR from github.com and it was merged.
https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor/pull/5

This issue is resolved and now I am using the code from pypi without any problem on my project.